# Show div on click on button, then hide this div when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="selectPeriodRangePanel">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button id="period_select_range_btn">Select Range</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#period_select_range_btn").off().on("click", function(){
    $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").toggle();
});
```

When i click on button, the **selectPeriodRangePanel** `DIV` is opened. I would like to hide this `DIV` when i click outside of it.

How can i do that ?

Comment: have you tried `.focusout()` or `.blur()` ?

Comment: You need to have a document click event handler where you do that

Comment: @FMashiro No, what is this ?

Comment: The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus, and the blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. read more here:|
https://api.jquery.com/focusout/
https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: When clicking outside of button or DIV or both? Not clear what you are expecting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is("#period_select_range_btn")){
      $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").show();
    }else{
        $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectPeriodRangePanel" style="display:none">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button id="period_select_range_btn">Select Range</button>
```

Comment: It should be `if($(e.target).closest("#period_select_range_btn").length)` a `button` element can contains other element. BTW, the click event propagation could be stopped by other bound handler. But +1 because this works for OP's case but isn't a generic way

Comment: I didn't used `.closest()` because the selector is an id and couldn't (or shouldn't) have more than one element with one id in the same document. But thanks for the info, I will take in mind it for the future.

Comment: @kpucha I meant that: https://jsfiddle.net/n2kfmh9k/  And i think OP means when clicking outside DIV, not button but quite unclear imho

Comment: Ah ok I understood it now. In the jfiddle is working but I understood what you said, maybe the e.target is not the element with id in the selector, im not sure if it takes the button as clicked, but is better to prevent ;). Thanks.

Comment: @kpucha Ya exactly :)

Comment: Is not correct, because when I click on the **#selectPeriodRangePanel** this disappear.

Comment: @Vixed But OP expected behaviour is unclear. You understand the way i understood it but apparently not what OP was looking for. He marked this answer as correct one

Answer (score 5):

You can have a click handler for the document element, where if the click has happened outside then you can hide it.

```js
$("#period_select_range_btn").off().on("click", function() {
  $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").toggle();
});
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#selectPeriodRangePanel, #period_select_range_btn').length == 0) {
    $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").hide();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#selectPeriodRangePanel {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectPeriodRangePanel">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button id="period_select_range_btn">Select Range</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like:

Try this

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  var el = $(e.target).closest("#selectPeriodRangePanel, #period_select_range_btn").length != 0;
  $("#selectPeriodRangePanel").toggle(el);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectPeriodRangePanel" style="display:none">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button id="period_select_range_btn">Select Range</button>
```